# perl - update from two databases

Tags: sql, perl, mariadb, dbi

i have two databases in mariadb and i want to update two databases,

```
#Connect to the database1.
     my $db1 = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=db1;host=ip",
     "login", 'paswword',
     {'RaiseError' => 1});

 #Connect to the database2.
     my $db2 = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=db2;host=ip",
     "login", 'password',
     {'RaiseError' => 1});
```

## this query not work

```
my $query3 = $db1->prepare("
UPDATE worldmap.worldmap_table t1
SET t1.severity = 1000
WHERE t1.host IN
(SELECT h.name
FROM host_inventory as i, hosts as h WHERE i.hostid=h.hostid  and h.available=1)");

$query3->execute;
```

thanks for your response

Comment: Your logic is unclear. Please provide sample data from both tables as well as expected results, and an explanation of the logic.

Comment: Are both databases hosted on the same server? If so, it should be possible to write a sql query that directly updates one table from the other.

Comment: Your update query is invalid sql.  the IN operator should be followed by a comma separated list of values or a subquery.

Comment: So you want to pull data from one database and insert it into the other. Your Perl looks fine. Your SQL is incomplete. This is the same as if it were one database. You need to get the host ids out of your `@row`, and have a placeholder `?` in your UPDATE query.

Comment: You've already asked several similar questions. Have you understood any of the answers you were given?

Comment: this is not same question, now i use two database worldmap and zabbix

Comment: What is your problem? What error messages do you get? In the edited version of the question you do not use two databases.

Comment: the problem is $db1 is for database 1, but $query3 use database 1 and database 2

Comment: Are the `IP` values the same?

Comment: The question is clear: How can I use join/update/insert if the tables are on different databases on the same instance/server. Until now it seems there is no solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use a single connection.  Reference tables using the db.table syntax.